# Django models create data duplicate

Tags: python, django

1.Models's name is UserRecord.
2.Below is the code of my view.

```
@login_required
def data(request, page, keyword,strEncode):
    current_username = request.user.username
    data_s = dosomething() #It takes a long time!!!
    UserRecord.objects.get_or_create(user=User.objects.get(username=current_username),MyRecords=keyword) # in order to create unique value
    # or use below method
    # if not UserRecord.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=current_username),MyRecords=keyword):
        # UserRecord.objects.create(user=User.objects.get(username=current_username),MyRecords=keyword)
    return JsonResponse(data_s, safe=False)
```

Requested below URL several times with no interval,something like concurrent threading .
http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/1/test/english/
After this operation done,MyRecords column is populated by duplicate values.
I found something in Django document to use 'with transaction.atomic' to deal with this problem but it did not work.

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey(User)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql

```
class UserRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    MyRecords = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "MyRecords"),) #mutil column uique idex
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get user by **User.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=current_username))** 
Instead use request.user for same.

```
@login_required
def data(request, page, keyword,strEncode):
    current_user = request.user
    data_s = dosomething() 
    UserRecord.objects.get_or_create(user=current_user,MyRecords=keyword) # in order to create unique value
    return JsonResponse(data_s, safe=False)
```

And **MyRecords=keyword** will create a new record every time a new keyword is passed in the **def data** view, so please review your code.

Comment: <blink>class UserRecord(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
       MyRecords = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user.username  </blink>

Comment: @blueboy read your code carefully. The problem is in code you did not share.

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey(User),i mean no repeat records for current user.